# Getting Count with different conditions in Select Query

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

The scenario is I have a column named "States" in a table, States can be 0,1,2,3 or 4. What I want to do is get a count of each state using `WHERE State =` in a single query.

The main purpose is I want to show the count of records (identified by their state). Like this, **20 records have State 0** etc.

Is this possible? If yes, then how can I achieve this?

Edit: I know about `Count`. Here's what I have tried:

```
SELECT State, Date_Created, (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM [ECOS].[eco].[tb_projects_details] WHERE State=1) as State_One, (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM [ECOS].[eco].[tb_projects_details] WHERE State=2) as State_Two, (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM [ECOS].[eco].[tb_projects_details] WHERE State=0) as State_Zero, (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM [ECOS].[eco].[tb_projects_details] WHERE State=4) as State_Four FROM [ECOS].[eco].[tb_projects_details] WHERE Date_Created < dateadd(week,-3,getdate());
```

Comment: `count(state), state` and if the state is not present, then there is none.

Comment: what have you tried? can u give som data example? please take a read of [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Let's count how many identical answers we can get to this homework question.

Comment: First of all, it's not a homework question. Second, please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a list of values and their counts you can do this:

```sql
SELECT State, COUNT(*) AS C
FROM mytable
GROUP BY State
```

To generate one row that contains value counts as columns you can do this:

```sql
SELECT
COUNT(CASE State WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS State_0_Count,
COUNT(CASE State WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS State_1_Count,
COUNT(CASE State WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS State_2_Count,
COUNT(CASE State WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS State_3_Count,
COUNT(CASE State WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS State_4_Count
FROM [...]
WHERE [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you want to group and count:

```
SELECT   mt.States, COUNT(*) total
FROM     my_table mt
GROUP BY mt.States
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be very easy if you use `group by` clause after `where` condition. Then you will get the number of each state very easily.

```
SELECT state, count(*)
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY state
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time read a sql for beginers book first.

```
Select state, count(*)
from table 
group by state
```